# What are the benefits of rspec matchers versus vanilla ruby?

Tags: ruby, rspec

All tutorials on rspec use built-in matchers but I do not see the benefits given the cost of learning new syntax. For example, these two are equivalent:

```
expect(person.name).to eq "John" 
person.name.should == "John"
```

At least `eq` is something easy to remember. `rpsec` involves many more "exotic" things like `have(n).things`. Why shouldn't I use `object.size.should == n` in plain ruby instead?

In sum, what's the benefit of learning all these rspec matchers over using `.should ==`?

Comment: This question seems like it might be somewhat broad and opinion based, but a quick answer is that rspec can create a specification for the application which is more natural in words, I think DHH himself has said that [there's not much need for rspec or cucumber](http://www.rubyinside.com/dhh-offended-by-rspec-debate-4610.html) but that's his opinion, that article displays a few different view points that you can use to familiarize yourself with the arguments for/against.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.should` is *not* vanilla ruby - it is rspec just like `expect`...

`rspec` [introduced](http://myronmars.to/n/dev-blog/2012/06/rspecs-new-expectation-syntax) the `expect` syntax, because of inherent caveats in the `should` method:

> **Delegation Issues**   Between `method_missing`, `BasicObject` and the standard library’s delegate, ruby has very rich tools for building
>   delegate or proxy objects. Unfortunately, RSpec’s `should` syntax, as
>   elegantly as it reads, is prone to producing weird, confusing failures
>   when testing delegate/proxy objects.

Rspec API guidelines is to have tests read like english, that is why they have syntax like:

```
 object.should have(5).elements
```

Or with the new syntax

```
expect(object).to have(5).elements
```

Which means that you "expect object to have 5 elements", instead of having to explain the same this with

```
object.size.should == n
```

Comment: So the benefit is simply to have more English-like syntax? And `.should ==` can accomplish everything that built-in matchers like `eq` and `have(n).things` can do?

Comment: That is _not_ what I said. Like anything in code, there is more than one way to skin a cat, but limiting yourself to `.should ==` sounds silly - how would you `expect { save_new }.to change(saved_items, :size).by(1)`?